# How do I setup a trigger on a view in SQL server that inputs/updates a column's data into a table?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Sorry for not having a lot of information on this, but I'm still learning about SQL and would appreciate any help.

I'd like to setup a trigger on a view that activates after an update or insert, then updates a specific column on another table. The only methods I have for joining these two datasets are from a date, and from a person's name. Otherwise they do not share any other information.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is way too vague to get a real answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Is someone writing an explicit statement like `UPDATE dbo.NameOfView SET ...`?

Comment: Have you looked up `create trigger` ? And how far did you get when trying it ? If you post what you have already then maybe we can help with the part where you are stuck

Comment: I apologize for being too vague, I am trying to understands triggers in general but having some difficulty. 

I don't believe it is an explicit statement.

I didn't make it very far when trying to get it going, so i figured I needed to just address what i was trying to accomplish then go from there. thank you all for any assistance.

Comment: So what is the question? Your description indicates you expect a trigger on your view to fire when data in a table is updated. This is NOT how triggers work.

Comment: I'd like to setup a trigger that would update a table when a specific view is updated or has a new row inserted. I suppose if I understood how a trigger on one table affects another table that I could work with that. I appreciate your help. I'm just getting caught up in the details on how I can get this data from one to another.

Comment: A view is essentially a stored query, it is a bit more complicated than that but conceptually that works. Meaning rows aren't added to a view, they are added to the base table. So in your case you want to add a trigger to a table. The biggest issue here is still that you are not sharing any real details. You are talking in abstractions. What you really need to do here is share your table structure, the view and some details about what you want to happen. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Hmm. Okay I'm just going to throw this out there. I have some entries on one table being populated by ~4 people. At the end of the day they create another entry on a separate table. I would like to have a column automatically populate on the 2nd table with a count of the entries on the 1st table. I have a view setup for a report that goes out into excel which has done a lot of the heavy lifting, I figured pulling data off that when it's updated would be easier. Also since I don't have a direct link between the tables besides data and user, i have the view setup to cast the date as just a day.

Comment: BTW, I appreciate your help with the links, I realize I am going about this horrifically, but I figured I would branch out and try posting on this issue, I hope I can improve my approach, and your links are very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found to work, thank you for any help you provided. It may not be ideal, so if there is any advice, feel free to comment.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
ON TABLE1
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @INS NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @INS = NAMECOLUMN FROM INSERTED
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'BRIEF DESCRIPTION' 
END
IF @INS = ‘Last, First’

BEGIN

UPDATE TABLE1
SET DESTINATIONCOLUMN  =  EXAMPLE.CT

FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CT FROM TABLE2 WHERE NAMECOLUMN = ‘Last, First’) EXAMPLE
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'BRIEF DESCRIPTION' AND NAMECOLUMN = ‘Last, First’
END
BEGIN
```